# Slow performance on Hibernate + Java but fast when I use TOAD with the same native Oracle query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I've detected a performance problem with hibernate and native queries on Oracle. When I execute a complex SQL query with several parameters on TOAD I get the result in miliseconds. However, when I execute the same query using Hibernate this time is incremented hugely (up to four seconds or even more).

My SQL query is rather complex, return an unique value (so, the problem is not related with the time necessary to instation classes) and it contains several parameters with the the format ':nameParameter'. This query is stored in a String. For example,

```
String myNamedNativeQuery = "select count(*) from tables "+
                            "where column1 = :nameParameter1 "+ 
                            "and column2 = :nameParameter2";  
                            //actually my sentence is much more complex!!
```

When I execute the sentence on TOAD it is resolved in few miliseconds. But using this sentence with Hibernate

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("myNamedNativeQuery");

query.setParameter(nameParameter1, value1);
query.setParameter(nameParameter2, value2);

query.uniqueResult();
```

are necessary several seconds to get the same result.

I realized if I replaced the parameters directly on the native query and then I execute the sentence using Hibernate the time decreases drastically. It would be something like that:

```
String strQuery = session.getNamedQuery("myNamedNativeQuery").getQueryString();

myNamedNativeQuery = myNamedNativeQuery.replace("nameParameter1", value1);
myNamedNativeQuery = myNamedNativeQuery.replace("nameParameter2", value2);

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("myNamedNativeQuery");
query.uniqueResult();
```

Anybody knows what's happening??

Thanks in advance.

PS: The Oracle version is 9i and Hibernate 3.2

Comment: turn of the "show sql" option with hibernate.  It'll show you the query that hibernate is running and will give you insight into why it is taking so long.

Answer (score 7):

I think what's happening with this code :

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("myNamedNativeQuery");
query.setParameter(nameParameter1, value1);
query.setParameter(nameParameter2, value2);
query.uniqueResult();
```

is this:

at line 1 : a query plan is created based on some expected values for your named parameters.

at line 4 : the query is executed with value1 and value2, but those values are not "good values" for the query plan that was elaborate at line 1 and so, the database is executing a very inappropriate plan for the actual values and it takes a lot of time.

**Why ?**

Looking at the source code of `HibernateSessionImpl.createSQLQuery(...)` I found this line of code:

```
SQLQueryImpl query = new SQLQueryImpl(
                sql,
                        this,
                        factory.getQueryPlanCache().getSQLParameterMetadata( sql )
        );
```

which is calling `getQueryPlanCache()` with some parameterMetaData. I assume that this metadata is not *good enough*.

Comment: Interesting...So, what would the best practice be in these cases?? Maybe replacing the parameters with their values before calling createSQLQuery()?

Comment: Perhaps adaptive cursor sharing would help.  But that feature is not available until 11g.

Comment: According to my tests, this situation happens using session.getNamedQuery('myNamedQuery') as well. It seems that Hibernate is caching the query plans and with some parameters the chosen query plan are not the best. So, would it be possible to configurate the query plan cache?

Comment: You wrote that "time decreases drastically" so I don't understand why are you saying now that your second solution is not efficient ? Can you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: In my project I've lots of HQL and native SQL named queries stored into an XML. The most of them are executed as session.getNamedQuery('namedQuery').setParameter(...).uniqueResult(); If a query plan is calculated for a named query and later I execute the same named query but with other parameters the query plan cannot be the best, can it? So, is not it possible to elaborate the query plan using the parameters values?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to you is:

Remove all bind parameters and use StatelessSession instead of Session

Use SQLQuery instead of query with full SQL including parameter values

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
```

I had similar problem and till I get better solution,this is what I managed to make it work.
See  [Hibernate parameterized sql query slow and active oracle sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32596761/1266286?stw=2)

Answer (score 0):

`<property name = "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>`

Add this to your hibernate.cfg.xml or update your application properties file.