# Hibernate, Query SQL with params. Bad Performance

Tags: performance, oracle, hibernate, jpa, glassfish

I have an issue related to the performance of a SQL query using JPA.

Response time:

- Using Toad - **200 ms**
- Inside my project using **Glassfish 2.1, Java 1.5, Hibernate 3.4.0.ga** - **27 s**

**Oracle 10g**

Glassfish and Toad are hosting in the same machine. I have connected to other ddbb from the same Glassfish, JPA, etc, and performance is good. so I don't know what is happening.

I have two different environments. In one of this (the worst, theoretically) it runs fast. In the other, it's where I have the problem.

The query is executed with a **Javax.persistence.Query** object and in this object are inserted the parameters with the method setParameter(). After that, I call to getResultList() method and this method returns the registers to me. In this point is where the time is excessive.

**But, if I replace the parameters in code and I call to getResultList() method directly, without setting parameters into Query object, the performance is much better.**

Anyone could help me with any clue about the problem or how to trace it?

**Query**

```
SELECT A, B, ..., DATE_FIELD FROM
     (SELECT A, B, C FROM Table1 
        WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(A, NVL(UPPER(:A),'')) AND DATE_FIELD = :DATE
        UNION
      SELECT A, B, C FROM Table2 
        WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(A, NVL(UPPER(:A),'')) AND DATE_FIELD = :DATE)
```

**Java Code**

```
public Query generateQuerySQL(String stringQuery, HashMap<String, Object> hParams) {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(stringQuery);
    if (hParams != null) {
        for (Iterator<String> paramNameList = hParams.keySet().iterator();  paramNameList.hasNext() {
            String name = paramNameList.next();
            Object value = hParams.get(name);
            query.setParameter(name, value);
           }
       }
    return query;
   }
```

Comment: The only possibilities is the size of data sets or query caching configuration at database.

Comment: Show real code example please. Entity, JPA query, e.t.c.

Comment: @Taky, Now you can see the query and Java code.

Comment: Finally, it seems a bug of hibernate with date tyoe params. If I replace this date to String, the performance is right

Answer (score 2):

`Query query = em.createNativeQuery(stringQuery);`

will elaborate a query plan to execute the query. Unfortunally the metadata that is used to elaborate the query plan do not fit the actual parameters values that will be used when the query will be executed.

If you substitute the parameter before elaborating the plan : the plan is fine and run very fast.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294735/slow-performance-on-hibernate-java-but-fast-when-i-use-toad-with-the-same-nati/14295140#14295140)

Comment: I have tested using parameters and avoiding the DATE type, and the performance is good. I think that the problem comes from the Date param. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should change **cursor_sharing = FORCE** in oracle to enable hibernate support in JPA for oracle.

[please refer to following for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_influence.htm#TGSQL251)