# spring-data-jpa repository and hibernate nested query

Tags: hibernate, subquery, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently running into an issue that I suspect may be an issue with either Hibernate or Spring Data JPA. My underlying relational database is Oracle PL/SQL.

I have a simple subinterface of Spring Data's JpaRepository as such:

```
@Component
@Repository
public interface MyEmailRepository extends JpaRepository<Email, Integer> {

@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE email e" +
        "SET e.toAddress = 'someValue' " +
        "WHERE e.foreign_key IN ( SELECT f.primary_id FROM Feeder f WHERE f.ids in (:ids) )")
int deleteTheEmail(@Param("ids") List<Integer> ids);
```

As you can see, this is a nested query. When this code executes, the thread seems to hang for a very long time and nothing gets accomplished, unless I manually kill the process. If I execute this same query with something like SQL Developer, the query runs very quickly.

Any ideas, suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294735/slow-performance-on-hibernate-java-but-fast-when-i-use-toad-with-the-same-nati/14295140#14295140 (my guess : the query plan elaborate by hibernate is not effecient at all)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. The issue was there were table locks on the underlying table due to some resource leak....i.e, unclosed connections/dangling transactions.